# web scraping, extracting href from product grid

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cloudflare

I am working on a webscraper using cloudscraper and beautiful soup (I am new to this). For 1 webpage ([https://www.feelunique.com/makeup?filter=fh_location=//c1/en_GB/categories%3C{c1_c1c6}/!exclude_countries%3E{gb}/!site_exclude%3E{1}/!brand={a70}/%26special-page=dept_home%26customer-country=GB%26site_id=1%26gender=female%26device=desktop%26site_area=department%26date_time=20210429T060257%26fh_view_size=40%26fh_start_index=0%26fh_view_size=40](https://www.feelunique.com/makeup?filter=fh_location=//c1/en_GB/categories%3C%7Bc1_c1c6%7D/!exclude_countries%3E%7Bgb%7D/!site_exclude%3E%7B1%7D/!brand=%7Ba70%7D/%26special-page=dept_home%26customer-country=GB%26site_id=1%26gender=female%26device=desktop%26site_area=department%26date_time=20210429T060257%26fh_view_size=40%26fh_start_index=0%26fh_view_size=40)) I am trying to scrape the links of each product in a product grid.

I have written this code:

```
    baseurl = 'https://www.feelunique.com/'
    productlinks = []
    productlinks2 = []

        r = scraper.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        for a in soup.select("#fullcolumn > div.eba-component.eba-product-listing"):
            print(a)
            if a.has_attr('href'):
                productlinks.append(baseurl + a['href'])
                print(len(productlinks))
```

And when I print `a` I get the relevant HTML and tags, but can't seem to grab the href from these. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

By using a better selector, your problem will be resolved.

Just replace the below-the-line.

```
for a in soup.select("a[class='Product-link thumb']"):
```

Regards,